# Can't figure out why strcpy isn't copying string effectively?

Tags: c

I'm trying to construct a program that has the user input the date in this format '01'14'2013', and outputs it into this format 'january 14, 2013'. I am trying to copy the string that holds the input from the user onto a different string, to later concatenate it onto the original string without the first and second index of the strings, so that I only have '/14/2013', from the original string, and then replace the '/' with ' ' so that it reads the month, day and the year....but for some reason, when I try to copy the original string from input onto another string( the one I plan to concatenate later), it doesn't copy effectively, am i missing something..?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() 
{ 

char date[100]; 


   char month[100]; 
   char array[12][100] ={"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}; 
   char month2[100]; 

   printf(" Please enter a date "); 
   fgets( date, 100, stdin); 

 strcpy(month2, month);  

 if( date[0] == '0' && date[1] == '1')
 {
   strcpy(month, array[0]); 
 }
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '2')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[1]);
 }
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '3')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[2]);
 }   
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '4')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[3]);
 }
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '5')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[4]);
 }   
 else if( date[0] == '0' && date[1] == '6')
 {
   strcpy(month, array[5]); 
 }
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '7')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[6]);
 }
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '8')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[7]);
 }   
 else if( date[0] =='0' && date[1] == '9')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[8]);
 }
 else if( date[0] =='1' && date[1] == '0')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[9]);
 }   
 else if( date[0] =='1' && date[1] == '1')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[10]);
 }
 else if( date[0] =='1' && date[1] == '2')
 { 
   strcpy(month, array[11]);
 }   









 printf("%s \n", month); 
 printf("%s \n", month2); 
 return 0; 

}
```

Comment: What do you expect from `strcpy(month2, month);` ?

Comment: You probably want strcat, since strcpy just trashed the destination string everytime you copy into it.strcat will append.

Comment: The `100` in `month[12][100]` seems like overkill; September has 9 letters, so `month[12][10]` would be big enough. However, it doesn't cause any failure.  Surely it would be better to convert `date[0]` and `date[1]` into a number (int n = (date[0] - '0') * 10 + (date[1] - '0');`, and then use `strcpy(month, array[n]);`, possibly after validating that the `date[0]` is a `'0'` or `'1'`, and `isdigit(date[1])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(month2, month);
```

Neither `month` nor `month2` have been initialized to anything useful at this point.  Their contents are indeterminate and calling `strcpy` with something other than a properly terminated C-string invokes undefined behavior.

Looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 0):

Lesser code, But without some validations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char date[100];

        char month[100];
        char array[12][100] = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        printf(" Please enter a date ");
        fgets( date, 100, stdin);

        char month2[100];
        strcpy(month2, date);
        month2[2] = '\0';

        strcpy(month, array[atoi(month2) - 1]);

        printf("%s \n", month);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct mon {
    const char *name;
    const int len;
} Month;

#define M(x){ x " ", sizeof(x)}

Month month[] = { {"", 0}, //dummy
    M("January"), M("Febuary"), M("March"), M("April"),
    M("May"), M("June"), M("July"), M("August"),
    M("September"), M("October"), M("November"), M("December")
}; 


int main(){
    char in_date[128];
    char out_date[128] = "";
    int m = 0, pos;
     printf(" Please enter a date E.g MM/DD/YYYY\n");
     fgets( in_date, sizeof(in_date), stdin);

    if(in_date[0] == '0'){
        if(isdigit(in_date[1]) && in_date[1] != '0'){
            m = in_date[1] - '0';
            pos = month[m].len;
            memcpy(out_date, month[m].name, pos);
        }
    } else if(in_date[0] == '1'){
        if('0' <= in_date[1] && in_date[1] <= '2'){
            m = 10 + in_date[1] - '0';
            pos = month[m].len;
            memcpy(out_date, month[m].name, pos);
        }
    }
    if(m){
        memcpy(out_date + pos, in_date + 3, 7);
        out_date[pos + 2] = ',';
        out_date[pos + 7] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", out_date); 
    } else {
        printf("invalid month\n");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```